# TCP port 43 Whois servers

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, dns, whois

Hi network programmers

I would like to know if there is

1) any up-to-date single whois server for PHP socket port 43 lookup of single domain names of (almost) any TLD ?

2) any list or information of up-to-date of whois servers for PHP socket port 43 lookup of single domain names having specific TLD ?

My current experience is that all whois servers for port 43 for single TLDs are all NOT returning:

registrant contact information
Admin contact information
technical contact information
or
name server information

For example the whois server whois.verisign-grs.com for .com TLD does not have any information about registrant, admin contact or technical contact. Such kind of information do a whois server returns - if it is relevant to me :)

Hope you will give me some useful help :)

Comment: This post has some Whois lookup APIs in the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api

In particular: https://www.mashape.com/nametoolkit/name-toolkit#!documentation and http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/

Comment: Hi again

Thanx for your answer

I have to say that in the definition file is listed whois host whois.verisign-grs.com for .com TLD.

I have already tried this whois server - but the results of this whois server does not have any information about registrant, admin contact or technical contact.

Such kind of information do a whois server returns - if it is relevant to me :)

I hope that you out there in cyber will give a link to a list that fulfil what's relevant to me :)

QHansen

Comment: The mashup.com/nametoolkit/name-toolkit seems to provide registrant information?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) any up-to-date single whois server for PHP socket port 43 lookup of single domain names of (almost) any TLD ?

No, there is no single whois server. Every registry provides its own.

> 2) any list or information of up-to-date of whois servers for PHP socket port 43 lookup of single domain names having specific TLD ?

Have a look at [this definition file](https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/master/data/tld.json).

> My current experience is that all whois servers for port 43 for single TLDs are all NOT returning: registrant contact information Admin contact information technical contact information or name server information

It depends on the registry. Each registry has different policies.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve registrant information from thin WHOIS registries (like Verisign), you need to query the appropriate server for the domain's current registrar. The referral information is embedded in the response from Verisign's WHOIS server, e.g.

```
Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM
Registrar: NAME.COM, INC.
Whois Server: whois.name.com         <--- THIS LINE
Referral URL: http://www.name.com
Name Server: NS1.SERVERFAULT.COM
Name Server: NS2.SERVERFAULT.COM
Name Server: NS3.SERVERFAULT.COM
Name Server: NS4.SERVERFAULT.COM
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Updated Date: 17-feb-2014
Creation Date: 26-dec-2003
Expiration Date: 26-dec-2015
```

This indicates that you should perform the same query against `whois.name.com` to get full results.

**Note that the Terms of Service for most WHOIS servers, including Verisign's, prohibit high-volume automated access.** Performing mass queries may cause you to be blocked.

Comment: This only applies to thin registries, typically .COM/.NET only today and before they become a thick registry as currently planned for 2018/2019